# rename batch files mac remove first word

Tags: macos, automator

I am trying to rename a batch of files on mac.

The files look like

122-Test-12.jpg

I need the output file as

Test-12.jpg

I been trying to use automator but i dont know what am doing.

Comment: More suited for [SU]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use AppleScript:

```
set myFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)
repeat with aFile in myFiles
    set aFile to contents of aFile
    tell application "Finder"
        set fileName to aFile's name
        set firstDash to offset of "-" in fileName
        set aFile's name to text (firstDash + 1) through -1 of fileName
    end tell
end repeat
```